# How to mass install Edubuntu on a Chromebook?

Tags: system-installation, edubuntu

I've been asked to post my question here from /r/ubuntu on Reddit.

I'm prepping a computer-lab in a box project for a school in Malawi, Africa. One of my tasks is replacing the ChromeOS with Edubuntu. I know the steps to update one computer; but I'd like to update in batches of 8 or all 32 if i have enough networking ports. Anyone know of a way to do a mass install of Ubuntu on Chromebooks?

Comment: You may want to look into doing a network stored image, and doing PXE boot.

Comment: So far I have not found reliable information on PXEBooting a Chromebook. I'll have the hardware soon, so I will answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a fully automatic installation with [FAI project](http://fai-project.org/) this could be done using PXE install or an unattended CD installation. Many other options are also available.

You can see what could be done in the following youtube video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yLIZL_iyAww

Comment: Yeah I think PXE is not available in a Chromebook.